# flat_map in Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

Using Ruby 1.8.7, is there built-in functionality similar to `Array.map` which allows for the return of multiple values instead of just one? E.g. I have an array and each element contains an array - I want to end up with all values from the inner arrays. For instance, an array of states where each as an array of counties - I want a an array of ALL counties.

```
@states.map_many { |o| o[:states] }
```

Same as `Array.flat_map` in newer versions of Ruby. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `array.map { ... }.flatten`.

To get all counties, you'd use...

```
@counties = @states.map { |o| o[:states] }.flatten
```

If you wish to flatten by only one level (which `flat_map` does in current versions of Ruby), you can pass a `1` to `flatten`. This is unnecessary for your example, as you are building an array with at most two dimensions.